# My VSCODE (SFDX) is not running - Command failed with ENOENT: npm

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vs-code

All was working fine till the morning untill, in the afternoon when i tried to run some create LWC commands. Now, no SFDX commands will work, i am getting the following error :

```
04:30:38.633 sfdx force:lightning:component:create --componentname myComponent2 --outputdir force-app/main/default/aura
ERROR running force:lightning:component:create:  Command failed with ENOENT: npm root -g --prefix /Users/padmajasubhash/Documents/SFDX Projects/Surya Practice/.yo-repository --loglevel error
spawnSync npm ENOENT
04:30:39.881 sfdx force:lightning:component:create --componentname myComponent2 --outputdir force-app/main/default/aura
 ended with exit code 1
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you run sfdx update to see if it fixes this.

Comment: Try restarting your computer. That tends to fix this error.

Comment: @sfdcfox : Tried that, still not working.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava : Already upto date

Comment: It seems like the project wasn't generated properly. Try creating an empty `.yo-repository` folder in `/Users/padmajasubhash/Documents/SFDX Projects/Surya Practice`. That might fix it, though it doesn't fix the initial problem

Comment: I was able to resolve this by downloading and running the latest CLI installer, revisiting the "Make VS Code Salesforce Ready" module: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce/vscode-salesforce-ready

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please visit- https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and install node.js on your machine. This is not a vs code extension.
Restart VS code after install.

Comment: Yup, don't know why but this started working fine after i installed node js. It used to work fine before. Well, anyway, it works now.